# Docx Module not installing

Tags: python, xcode, visual-studio-code, module

```
    import docx
```

And I Get an Error

```
     import docx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
```

I have tried using

```
pip install python-docx
```

and I get:

```
  Requirement already satisfied: python-docx in c:\users\16dea\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (0.8.11)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=2.3.2 in c:\users\16dea\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from python-docx) (4.6.3)
```

what could be the issue? I have uninstalled and installed a few times, i have unistalled python entirely and reinstalled

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Has your question been fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Triy to install docx with:

> `pip install python-docx`

Answer (score 0):

Modules are usually stored in `current selected interpreter\lib\site-packages` if you use `pip` to install, which can be verified by the command `pip show <modulename>`:

[image]

Delete the module in the folder your question mentioned, then reload vscode. After selecting interpreter, open a new integrated Terminal then reinstall `python-docx`.